# NHibernate: ProjectionList: Can we create dynamic projectionlist for Orderby

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

I am working on a query in NHibernate in which user could provide a sorting order for some selected fields. I need to do a `OrderBy()` in *QueryOver* with the names of field names in entities, but when using projection list I am getting like this.

```
SELECT
     this_.Number as y0_,
     scc3_.Code as y1_,

FROM sometable
WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY this_.Number as y0_,
 scc3_.Code as y1_ asc
```

The projection list for select columns is different from orderby projection list and I am not using `.WithAlias()`

```
sortProjectionList.Add(Projections.Property(() => stock.Number));
sortProjectionList.Add(Projections.Property(() => scc.Code));
```

How can I create a projectionlist without aliases or aliases with custom names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect, that you experience an issue with generated keyword "AS" inside of the `ORDER BY` in case, that you pass projections like this:

```
// NHibernate will leave few AS, except the last
query.OrderBy(sortProjectionList).Asc();
```

To avoid that, we can do it like this:

```
// NHibernate will solve each projection separately
for (var index = 0; index < sortProjectionList.Length; index++)
{
    query.OrderBy(sortProjectionList[index]).Asc();
}
```